# Read specific line from csv file on php

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

How do I get the second line from this CSV file?

```
 <?php

        $file = file('list.csv');
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
            print_r($line);  
        }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iterator to apply condition

```
 $file = file('list.csv');
 $i = 0;
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if($i == 1){
      print_r($line);
      break;
    }
    $i++      
 }
```

Comment: I've a too big file, so I don't want to loose time reading all the file and then catch the line that a I want. I want to fetch the exact line to turn the process faster.

Comment: just use break in if

Comment: @vinoli I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `file()` reads the file into an array, so you don't need that - just open it using `fopen()` (and don't forget to close it), then if you only want the second line, then just call `fgetcsv()` twice...

```
$file = fopen('list.csv', r);
$line = '';
if (fgetcsv($file) !== FALSE) {
    $line=fgetcsv($file);  
}
fclose($file);
```